# Kudu nested field

Tags: apache-spark, nested, apache-kudu

I have questions about Kudu with nested fields.

I have JSON from Kafka like this:

```
{
  "ts": 32,
  "status": "success",
  "uid": "3232",
  "url": "http://some_url",
  "syncpixel": "http://some_url",
  "dfp": {
    "DFP_UABrowser": "Chrome 61",
    "DFP_UAOperatingSystem": "Windows 7 ver.7.0",
    "JavascriptDisplayData_Screen_W_x_H": "1440 x 900",
    "Native_client": true
  }
}
```

`dfp` field has a nested object, I want to insert this object to kudu through Flume

I know that kudu does not support nested field, and supported binary column.
What do I need to do?

1. Convert field `dfp` to binary format and read for example scala spark?
2. Turn JSON in flatten format (but in many cases is not best issue, something like streaming product purchase with product id, name and other or products view in page).

Comment: Impala can not create Kudu tables with VARCHAR or nested-typed columns.

Answer (score 0):

If you use spark/scala streaming will not be and issue when you have proper setup cluster.
Read the entire json through spark and use "explode" function to flatten the json.
This will make life easier.

Comment: But this not an answer to the question.